# ToolkitScriptManager and Controls layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkitscriptmanager

2 questions.

I'm using vs2013 for web.
I try to add 2 combobox controls to the website but they appear on a new line.
I used google as always but didn't really found a good answer.
So my first question is, how do I successfully add 2 comboboxes out of the Ajax Toolkit on 1 line.

This code should all appear on one line:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server"></asp:ComboBox>
<asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox2" runat="server"></asp:ComboBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

yet this is the result, as you see, combobox 1 and 2 are on a new line while button1 and label2 are on the same line, because they are not from the AjaxControlToolkit.
[image: output]

Then my second question, I read things about using the ToolkitScriptManager instead of the ScriptManager. Why and How do I use this, when I add the ToolkitScriptManager to my page, it cannot find ToolkitScriptManager.cs
I don't know yet why I should add them, but it's probably necessary for fixing my first question.